# Associative array, iterating keys and values PHP LARAVEL

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, associative

I have this array:

```
array:43 [▼
  "ALFA ROMEO" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "145"
  ]
  "AUDI" => array:6 [▼
    0 => "A1"
    1 => "A3"
    2 => "A4"
    3 => "A5"
    4 => "AUDI 80"
    5 => "Q3"
  ]
  "BMW" => array:15 [▼
    0 => "116I"
    1 => "118I"
    2 => "318I"
    3 => "318IA"
    4 => "320I"
    5 => "320IA"
    6 => "325I"
    7 => "328I"
    8 => "330I"
    9 => "535I"
    10 => "X1"
    11 => "X3"
    12 => "X5"
    13 => "X6"
    14 => "Z4"
  ]
]
```

I'd like to do this:

Get the key(**ALFA ROMEO** / **AUDI** / **BMW**) and search this key in a table (*brands*), get the **id** of this brand and iterate the "ALFA ROMEO" inside array to get the model (**145**) and insert in a new table called model_car(brand_id, model). And do the same to AUDI, BMW etc.

I know this is easy, but my mind does not work!

Thank you.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below this may help you to achieve what you wanted.

```
/* Let $array be the array posted by you. */
foreach ($array as $key => $data) {
    /* Fetch brand id by name. Assuming the name field replace it by your own. */
    $brand = Brands::where('name', $key)->first();

    /* Prepare array of brand id and model to be mass inserted. */
    $brandModel = [];
    foreach ($data as $i => $model) {
        $brandModel[$i]['brand_id'] = $brand->id;
        $brandModel[$i]['model'] = $model;
    }
    ModelCar::insert($brandModel);        //Insert into the new table model_car
}
```

Comment: How did you know that `Brands` and `ModelCar` were classes, and how did you know his structure?

Comment: Welcome :) @PiterOrtiz